# How to find the longest string in a list of lists of strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

How to find the longest string in a list?

This list has both strings and list of strings.

a set of strings, but the weirdness comes in that the strings I'm checking are in lists and those lists are mixed in with strings in a larger list.

Example value for 'entries':

```
extries = [["this is text", "more text"], "another string"]
```

python code

```
length = 0
for i in entries:
        if(type(i) is list):
            for x in i:
                x = str(x)
            if length << len(max(i, key = len)):
                length = len(max(i, key = len))
        else:
            for i in entries:
                i = str(i)
                if length << len(i):
                    length = len(i)
```

This should make

```
length = len(max(["this is text","more text","another string"])
```

but it is making `length = 0`.

Comment: Please add what you _expect_ your code to be outputting for the example you gave, otherwise we are unsure what you mean by your question.

Comment: Also `<<` is not equal to `<`. In Python `<<` is a bitwise operation, and so your `if` statements will essentially always be `True` as long as `length != 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will give you the length of the largest string -- whether or not it is inside a subset.

```py
entries = [["this is text", "more text"], "another string"]

length = 0
for i in entries:
    if type(i) is list:
        value = len(max(i, key=len))
        if length < value:
            length = value
    else:
        value = len(i)
        if length < value:
            length = value

print(len("this is text"), len("more text"), len("another string"))
print(length)
```

Outputs:

```
12 9 14
14
```

Comment: Ah! The issue is the less than operators! In my original code, I used my C++ habits and did '<<', but python uses '<'! Thank you!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Old habits die hard!

Answer (score 1):

I'd break the code down in two, first have a function that flattens an arbitrarily deep list:

```py
def flatten(lst, ret):
    for x in lst:
        if type(x) == list:
            flatten(x, ret)
        else:
            ret.append(x)
```

Then just use it with your input and an empty list to get a flattened list out, and call max:

```py
temp = []
entries = [["this is text", "more text"], "another string"]
flatten(entries, temp)
max(temp, key=len)
```

Notice that this would also work with an input like this `entries = [[["this is text", "more text"]], ["another string"], "the longest string of them all"]`.

Comment: Nice, I had the same idea

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary deep nested lists, I would first make a list flattening function:

```
def flatten_nested_list(lst):
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            yield from flatten_nested_list(item)
        else:
            yield item
```

Then you can call [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) with `key=len` to get the longest word:

```
print(max(flatten_nested_list(entries), key=len))
# another string
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `ỳield from`, that's really nice!

Comment: You don't need to cast it as a list, you can pass the generator directly to max. Which makes it much more efficient than my solution (on top of the benefits of not being recursive).